# For $M=\{(x,y,z)| x=y=z\}$ and $N=\{(x,y,z)| x+y+z=0\}$ show that $\mathbb{R}^3=M\oplus N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

With usual operations $\mathbb{R}^3$ ( as a $\mathbb{R}$ module).

For $M=\{(x,y,z)| x=y=z\}$ and $N=\{(x,y,z)| x+y+z=0\}$ show that $\mathbb{R}^3=M\oplus N$

My attempt:

$M=\{(x,x,x)| x\in \mathbb{R}\}$

$N=\{(x,-x-z,-x-y)|x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}\}$

$M+N=(x,-z,-y)$

Is this enough to show that?

Comment: @APCorreia No, this doesn't even show $M+N=\mathbb{R}^3$. Firstly, assuming the way things are defined in $N$, there is a relation between $x,y,z$ and so $(x-z,-y)$ is not an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Also, worth pointing out that the first component should be $2x$ not $x$ in $(x,-z,-y)$ but that's another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall demonstrate that $\mathbb{R}^{3} = M\oplus N$.

To begin with, let $v\in M+N$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
v = (a,a,a) + (c,d,-c-d) = a(1,1,1) + c(1,0,-1) + d(0,1,-1)
\end{align*}

Since $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,1,1),(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\}$ is LI and spans $M + N$, we conclude $M + N = \mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Now it remains to prove that $M\cap N = \{0\}$.

If $v\in M\cap N$, then we have that
\begin{align*}
v & = (a,a,a) = (c,d,-c-d) \Rightarrow a = 0 \Rightarrow v = (0,0,0)
\end{align*}
and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, $v_1=(\frac{a+b+c}{3},\frac{a+b+c}{3},\frac{a+b+c}{3})$ is a vector in $M$.

Also, $v_2=(\frac{2a-b-c}{3},\frac{-a+2b-c}{3},\frac{-a-b+2c}{3})$ is a vector in $N$ as the sum of its components is $0$.

Observe that, $v_1+v_2=v$.

So certainly, $M+N=\mathbb{R}^3$. But actually, this is a direct sum. If $(d,d,d)\in M$ is also in $N$, then, $3d=0$ so that means $d=0$. i.e. $M\cap N=\{(0,0,0)\}$.